# contact form 7 not sending mail

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, plugins, contacts

please av tried all the kind of settings i know on my wordpress website with the contact form 7 pluging trying to send mail to my admin email but it kept saying error trying to send your message try again later please i really need help guys there is alot i dont know help with this please thanks alot.
i already tried everything i know but seems its not enough and not working at all
The error debugging output is shown below:

error message -> There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.

Comment: Enable debug mode, try to send email again and check for errors in your debug log. Probably there might be some error. If there is no error, make sure emails are sent from your site using some SMTP plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post some error message from debug log?

The easiest and most effective way to fix the Contact Form 7 is not sending email issue for most people is to use WP Mail SMTP plugin. You can try the free version of it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: Thanks alot, that really helped, but I also need images uploaded to be displaying on the email from contact form but this isn't showing pls help